# Url Manager issue in Yii

Tags: php, regex, yii, url-routing, yii-url-manager

I am following url rules:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        'rescues/rescueprofile/<id:\d+>'=>'rescues/rescueprofile',
     // '<controller:\w+>/<breed:\w+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '/breeds/<breed:[^\/]+>' => 'breeds/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',

        'rescues/learn/<param1:\w+>'=>'rescues/learn',
        'breeds/<breed:\w+>'=>'breeds/view',
        'rescues/rescueprofile/<id:\d+>'=>'rescues/rescueprofile',
        'rescues/createadoptapplication/<id:\d+>'=>'rescues/createadoptapplication',
        'rescues/viewapplication/<id:\d+>'=>'rescues/viewapplication',
        'rescues/editdog/<id:\d+>'=>'rescues/editdog',
        'rescues/updateinfo/<name:\w+>'=>'rescues/updateinfo',
        'training'=>'rescuetraining',
        '<training:\w+>/<id:[a-zA-Z0-9 -]+>'=>'rescuetraining/view/<id:\w+>',
        'login'=>'site/login'
    ),
```

For rescuetraining controller, I have different urls `http://strutmymutt.com/training/life-rewards` and `http://strutmymutt.com/training/sit` but last one "`training/sit`" is not working. I tried so many different ways. If I add something "-" to sit and some chars then it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move this rule to the top of all the other rules

```
'<training:\w+>/<id:[a-zA-Z0-9 -]+>'=>'rescuetraining/view/<id:\w+>',
```

I also strongly suggest you move these default catch-all rules to the bottom/end of the array:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

---

**Explanation:**

`training/sit` will match this rule first:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
```

however, you do not have a controller called `trainingController` with an action inside called `sitAction()`. Yii throws a 404 instead because it can't find that controller file. Make sure the general rules like these are placed at the bottom/end of the array.